# Turn existing Red Hat Server into desktop VM

Tags: virtualization, redhat, virtual-machines, packages

Is it possible to download an existing Red Hat installation and use this in a VM that I can run on the desktop.

The problem I'm trying to solve is building an exact replicate of a production server to run locally so we can debug specific issues with package compatibility without breaking everything.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur with lain.

A few tips-

1)install VMWare tools.

2) sometimes VMWare converter changes your interface from eth0 to eth1, because it see's it as a new physcial nic. Just add the IP configuration to the new interface.

Also, read up about time and Linux Guest OSes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standalone VMware vCenter [converter](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/4_0) to do the physical to virtual conversion. Once you've done that then you can either use another VMware product to run it in or do further conversion to your chosen host environment.

Comment: Damn beat me to it.